# Custom keyboard for a textfield without the standard keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to write an app that uses a custom keyboard. How can I write code that prevents the iPhone keyboard from popping up. I have seen a custom keyboard that enters text in other iPhone applications, so I know that it is possible.

Comment: The keyboard has many different modes. Are you sure that it is a custom one? If yes, create a new view controller and build it yourself with buttons and methods.

Comment: I did create a custom keyboard on the view controller, but when I touched the textfield, the iPhone keyboard appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`inputView` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW22) that's present on every view (inherited from `UIResponder`).

Comment: I did create a custom keyboard on the view controller, but when I touched the textfield, that iPhone keyboard appeared.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by using a label instead of a textfield.